# gulp inject series with suffix

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

**Statement**: I`m working on an app which has a lot of updates in the form of new components(html, js and css files). The problem that I was encountering was that the js files would need a clear cache or a few browser page refresh in order to use the new ones as intended so the fix we though about was to version the js and css files through gulp since we already use it.

**Problem**: trying to inject files in html with gulp-inject as series and adding suffix not working. The files are injected but the suffix is not attached.

**Code**:

```
gulp.task("inject", function () {
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();

    var css_vendor = gulp.src([path.dirs.dist + "/vendor/**/*.css", path.dirs.dist + "/vendor.css"], {read: false});
    var css_other = gulp.src([path.dirs.dist + "/**/*.css", "!" + path.dirs.dist + "/vendor/**/*.css", "!" + path.dirs.dist + "/vendor.css", "!" + path.dirs.dist + "/main*.css", "!" + path.dirs.dist + "/components*.css"], {read: false});
    var css_main = gulp.src([path.dirs.dist + "/main*.css"], {read: false});
    var css_components = gulp.src([path.dirs.dist + "/components*.css"], {read: false});
    var js_vendor = gulp.src([path.dirs.dist + "/**/vendor*.js", "!" + path.dirs.dist + "/**/FileAPI*"], {read: false});
    var js = gulp.src([path.dirs.dist + "/**/cex*.js", "!" + path.dirs.dist + "/**/FileAPI*"], {read: false});

    return gulp.src([path.dirs.dist + "/index.html"])
        .pipe(inject(series(css_vendor, css_other, css_main, css_components, js_vendor, js), {relative: true}, {
            addSuffix: timestamp
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dirs.dist));
});
```

Comment: you don't get an error ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not add plain numbers or text as suffix for gulp-inject, suffix should means something, Try something like this instead:

```
addSuffix: '?' + timestamp
```

Just note that if you're going to use this approach, you should give up proper caching!

Comment: this approach breaks down the inject and there is nothing injected in the html file. it appears that addSuffix does not work even with a string.

Comment: @Blitz try only a source and don't use series(), to see if it works or not, if it did not work, use this suffix: `addSuffix: '?ver=1'` and see how it goes.